# Access Docker Container on localhost rather than 172.17.0.1

Tags: linux, iptables, docker

Ive pulled and built a docker container on ubuntu to run on a web server. The container is essentially an api that needs to be called from another app on the same server.

This is my DockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04


RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3-pip

# Install Dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install  --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


COPY search_api.py .
COPY search/ search

ENV DEBUG 0


CMD [ "gunicorn", "--workers", "2", "--threads", "1", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5050", "--timeout", "400", "search_api:app"]
```

This is my yml file

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    engine:
        image: engine:0
        restart: always
        ports:
           - 5050:5050
```

When the container is running it claims to be on port 5050 of 0.0.0.0

```
 0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp
```

Because I'm trying to access the docker container from outside in the host server, it seems like I can't map the actual docker container to hosts 5050 port, instead it goes to 172.17.0.1:5050. I was wondering if theres any way to push the docker contain all the way to the hosts port

The curious thing is when I do netstat -tulpn I get this

```
tcp6       0      0 :::5050                 :::*                    LISTEN      2487/docker-proxy-c
```

So port 5050 proxies to Docker, but then if I do localhost:5050 why shouldn't that bring me to the docker container? Based on everything I've tested so far, If I curl localhost:5050 it throws a curl (56) err. When I curl 172.17.0.1 from docker0, I get the results I want. Is there any way to reconfigure the docker container so it points to localhost?

Edit: Error from curls

```
[root@host etc]# curl localhost:5050
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
[root@host etc]# curl -4 localhost:5050
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Please include the entire error message from curl. And does it make a difference if you run `curl -4 localhost:5050`?

Comment: [root@host etc]# curl localhost:5050
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer, curl-4 throws same error